# Is it considered good practice to use **kwargs prolifically to aid readability?

Tags: python, class, pep8

When designing classes, I found it awkward to place default argument values in the `__init__` method, as in:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self, y=2, z=3):
        self.y = self.manip_y(y)
        self.z = self.manip_z(z)

    def manip_y(self, y):
        return y * 10

    def manip_z(self, z):
        return z - 30
```

Is it considered better practice to add `**kwargs` to function signatures to place default values in the function signatures as well?:

```
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.y = self.manip_y(**kwargs)
        self.z = self.manip_z(**kwargs)

    def manip_y(self, y=2, **kwargs):
        return y * 10

    def manip_z(self, z=3, **kwargs):
        return z - 30
```

Comment: What do you find awkard about your first example?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - why would e.g. `manip_y` be a public instance method? Will it ever be called from outside `__init__`?

Comment: How does "using kwargs prolifically" *aid* readability? Although not always the case, the example shown with kwargs is a good bit *harder* to follow.

Comment: I don't really know how your 2nd example could improve readability. You still have to have the `y=2` and `z=3` defaults (but in different places) that you claim is awkward, but now you have the `**kwargs` everywhere too.

Comment: kwargs does not aid readabilty at all if anything it hurts readablity

Comment: `**kwargs` and `*args` are designed for cases in which you don't know what arguments you will be given. It generally makes things less readable, but more robust. To see examples of cases in which `**kwargs` is necessary, and learn a bit about the MRO on the side, I recommend the famous "Super Considered Harmful" post: https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

Comment: Note that your `manip_y` and `manip_z` are methods "in name only." They ignore the instance's built-in `y` and `z` values, and use only the parameter values. If this is really what you intend, note that you are not really "manipulating" your values, as much as just running a function. You might consider decorating those methods with `@staticmethod` and dropping the `self` to make this more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to add default values in the `__init__` signature -- that way someone only needs to look at the signature to figure out the options. And, in example 2, the default values are now hidden in other functions. Additionally, your documentation will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

do not do this. why? because it forces you to read not only the `__init__` code to understand how to create the object but also *all of the functions called therein*.